# Using FBA in particular pages in SharePoint 2010 internet site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, fba

I want to use FBA (username/password) in some X pages in an internet SP 2010 site, so the desired design  is:

- for all site pages (except X page) the site will use the windows auth with anonymous access enabled
  so the internet/public users can view home page, contact us, about us.... without asking them to login
- when the anonymous user opens the X page, then he/she will be asked to login (using FBA) by providing username/password

is this applicable, if yes please provide hints/steps

thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible exactly as you say. Authentication is per Web Application in SharePoint. You can have a Web Application which supports two authentication mechanisms by "Extending" it. By using alternate access mappings you could access your web application e.g. by going to http://extranet.myintranet.com as well as http://extranet - when using the external URL you are forced to use FBA, when using the internal URL you can use NTLM.

Comment: thnx moontear for the reponse.

this is the first time i will play with extending SP application.
i ill learn it then try your suggestion.... 

you will mke me to learn new thing :) thnx a million

Comment: If the answer is enough for you, you should consider accepting it (with the checkmark on the side)